# Jmx Monitoring: Possible to collect and visualize Jmx/Mbeans Data saved on Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, jmx, metrics, grafana

I have managed to collect `JMX` MetricsData from a Java Application and saved it on a `Cassandra` database (My project leader said to do so).

I know that it is possible to collect with `JmxTrans` directly from JMX- Endpoints and visualize it within `Grafana`/`Graphite`.

My Question is: can I collect the  JMX metrics data from cassandra and visualize it in Grafana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grafana requires something else (ie graphite, influxdb, [cyanite](http://cyanite.io/)) to store the data. So to answer your question (what I think your asking at least) of if grafana can pull the metrics from JMX itself, it would be "No".

That said you can make the collection easier and faster. JMX isn't a very efficient medium. Instead just have Cassandra send metrics directly to your graphite (or whatever reporter) instances using its graphite reporter. see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/pluggable-metrics-reporting-in-cassandra-2-0-2 for details. The steps in blog post are as follows:

1. Grab your favorite reporter jar (such as metrics-graphite) and add it to the server’s lib
2. Create a configuration file for the reporters following the sample.
   Start the server with `-Dcassandra.metricsReporterConfigFile=yourCoolFile.yaml` by adding it to `JVM_OPTS` in `cassandra-env.sh`

Example config:

```
graphite:
  -
    period: 60
    timeunit: 'SECONDS'
    hosts:
     - host: 'graphite-server.domain.local'
       port: 2003
    predicate:
      color: "white"
      useQualifiedName: true
      patterns:
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Cache.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ClientRequest.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Storage.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ThreadPools.+"
```

Comment: You mean that with this graphite reporter I should able to visualize custom column families? Because I do not want to display Cassandras Metrics - I want to visualize Metrics from an another Java application which are saved in Cassandra DB

Answer (score 1):

the question is old, but if you were to do it nowadays , i'd recommend using Prometheus as data source for Grafana along with it's JmxExporter agent on Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use Cassandra as the data store for the JMX metrics that you are collecting from other services; Grafana doesn't have that support yet (the available datastores are listed [here](http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/overview/).